# Add Map Pins Asynchronously IOs

Tags: ios, scroll, annotations, mapkit

I have an IOs app that adds annotations when they enter the visible map view. This works well and keeps the total pins on the map low however this also looks buggy as the annotations are only added to the map when map scrolling has finished/completed. Does anyone know a way to add pins to the map whilst it's still scrolling so that the experience is fluid?

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: Have you tried to use a `dispatch_async` block to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add annotaion to MapView on the main thread?

ex)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self?.mapView.addAnnotation(venueAnnotation)
})
```